# Connect line chart when using datasets with non-overlapping labels(timestamps)

Tags: charts

I have several datasets (approx. 10) that comes from user input and the labels (x-axis) will therefore almost never overlap between the datasets.

What i would like to do is connecting points from the same datasets (for instance bloodPressure) thru a "non-existing" datapoint when this is necessary - like in the graph below. I would not want to fake a datapoint to achieve this.

Any suggestions how to do this?

[image: The values are recorded at "random"/difference times and overlapping labels will therefore rarely happen]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found the answer in the Chart.js documentation. It is possible to skip the array of labels and instead create the datasets with a x and y value like in the screen dump.

Works fine!